# How to store Swift types (Date, Dictionary and others) in PostgreSQL with Vapor 3?

Tags: swift, xcode, postgresql, vapor, postico

I am using Vapor 3, Swift 5.1, PostgreSQL 12 and Postico 1.5.10 for my Backend. Question is: how to store Date (I mean Swift Date()) and Dictionary (example, [String : Int])?

To work with PostgeSQL, I am using Postico (I am quite newbie in PostgreSQL, that's why), please look at screenshot:
[image]

And, I just have seen how to store Arrays, but where I can find other types to store? For example, Enum?

I will be thankful for any help or advice!

Comment: You should not define tables in PostgreSQL, you should use Fluent which is a ORM that comes with Vapor. Google it or look it up in the Vapor documentation. https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/fluent/getting-started/

Comment: Thank you for your comment but each field has its type anyway. I understand that Fluent should choose it but how to do it?

Comment: You use the built-in swift types, String, Int, Date etc, when defining your structs/classes and Fluent will translate it for you.

Comment: When creating a table first time?

Comment: Take the time to work through a tutorial and/or read the documentation.

Comment: But where exactly?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for pushing me to the idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- for date `timestamp without time zone`
- for `[String: Any]` should be `jsonb`

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply. When I put "timestamp without time zone", Postico gives me this: PostgreSQL said: column "date" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone
Hint: You might need to specify "USING date::timestamp without time zone".

Comment: @Alex you could try to run vapor api-template to see which types it uses for ToDo model https://github.com/vapor/api-template

Comment: Yes, I have created a new table with the same name but  delete it from "fluent" table. Vapor created me a new table, like I expected! Thank you Mike! And Thank you @Joakim Danielson!

Comment: @Mike, but  "timestamp without time zone" does not want to save Date any way, error: Value of type 'String' required for key 'date.date'. So question is only about Date.